# wxpython builder similar to boa constructor

Tags: python, wxpython, builder

I search a python builder IDE for wxpython similar to boa constructor.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/), [DialogBlocks](http://www.dialogblocks.com/) and [wxDesigner](http://www.wxdesigner-software.de/), with both DialogBlocks and wxDesigner being commercial tools. There also used to be a open-source editor called wxFormBuilder, but the site hosting it seems down right now.

Comment: There's also a new project that's just getting started that you can read about here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/15/wxpython-eguid-editra-gui-designer-wysiwyg-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Boa constructor is working here....works with windows 10
 https://bitbucket.org/cwt/boa-constructor/overview

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.